# Disable Windows animations for a single user

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, non-admin

With the System Performance Options, I can enable or disable Windows animations and animation sets among a host of other options. This method sets these options for the entire system and requires administrative privileges.

[image: Performance Options]

How can I change this setting for an individual user without affecting any other user or requiring Administrator permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Windows does not offer its System Performance Options to individual users, it does provide an option in the [**Ease of Access Center**](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/disable-windows-10-animations/) (`Control Panel > Ease of Access`). Select the **Make computer easier to see** link, then in the **Make things easier on the screen to see** section, select the **Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)** option.

[image: Ease of Access Center]
[image: Ease of Access option]

As the option reads, this doesn't give the granular control that the **System Performance Options** section offers, but just disables most, if not all animations for the user.